# Storing data and image on Ethereum network

Tags: cryptography, storage, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I want to run a blogging site like Blogger.com on Ethereum network, I found IPFS is currently being used for data and image storage in blockchain but is it the best option or shall I go with legacy RDBMS for data and image storage and just map location with blockchain using hashes?

Please advise what is the best option, both from economic and technical perspective?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted. Is it too easy question or something?

Answer (score 1):

If we do not consider commercial variants of distributed databases, then the use of IPFS is quite consistent with the general idea of building a decentralized system. In principle, instead of IPFW, you can use a torrent network or S3 cloud storage. When using S3, the network fault tolerance will be higher, but you will be connected to a specific storage provider.

The disadvantages of IPFS include the inability to exchange data in the absence of direct communication between the sender and the recipient of the file, however, this can be corrected by special procedures for exchanging files through third nodes.

I am more involved in private enterprise networks and we widely use IPFS as part of them. From public projects - kekker.com